# I installed a tool for dotnet CLI, why command tool list did not show it?

Tags: .net-core, command-line-interface, dotnet-cli

Look at the screenshot so you can better understand my question.[image]

Why `dotnetsay` tool was not listed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why is dotnetsay tool not listed?

Please note that `dotnet tool list` command does help list all local tools available in the ***current directory***, if you installed `dotnetsay` as a global tool, you can use following command to list all ***global*** tools.

```
dotnet tool list -g
```

Test Result

[image]

For more information about `dotnet tool list` command, please check:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-tool-list#examples

Answer (score 6):

The answer for your question, to show your installed tool, use one of these ways:

```
dotnet tool list -g
dotnet tool list --global
dotnet tool list --tool-path C:\Users\samue
```

Practices these commands

Case install global:

```
dotnet tool uninstall dotnetsay --global
dotnet tool list

dotnet tool install dotnetsay --global
dotnet tool list --global
dotnetsay
```

Case install local:

```
mkdir C:\foo
dotnet tool uninstall dotnetsay --tool-path C:\foo
dotnet tool list --tool-path C:\foo

dotnet tool install dotnetsay --tool-path c:\foo
dotnet tool list --tool-path C:\foo
cd /d C:\foo
dotnetsay
```

Reference:

- `dotnet tool install` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-tool-install
- `dotnet tool list` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-tool-list